# Java: WebSocket server won't send data to client properly

Tags: websocket

Handshakes are done correctly and the server can decode the data coming from the client, but the client closes the connection when I try to send data to it.

I've been using http://websocket.org/echo.html as the client w. latest versions of Firefox & Chrome.

Here's the data frame I'm trying to send:

```
129 10000001
4 100
116 1110100
101 1100101
115 1110011
116 1110100
-------
fin:true
opcode:1
len:4
masked:false
masks:[0, 0, 0, 0]
payload:test
?♦test

http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5
      0                   1                   2                   3
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
     |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
     |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
     |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
     | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
     |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
     +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
     | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
     +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+


*/
```

And the server side method responsible for sending data to the client:

```
public void sendData(Socket socket, byte[] dataBytes){
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(dataBytes));
        //[-127, 4, 116, 101, 115, 116]
        for(byte b:dataBytes) System.out.println(Integer.toString((int)0xff&b,2));
        /*
        10000001
        100
        1110100
        1100101
        1110011
        1110100        
        */

        try{

                InputStream data = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataBytes);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                //tested with ByteArrayOutputStream and written data == dataBytes


                //out.write((byte)0x00); //tried with and without this
                if ( data != null )
                {
                // tried also out.write(dataBytes) intstead of this 
                        byte[] buff = new byte[2048];
                        while (true)
                        {
                                        int read = data.read( buff, 0, 2048 );
                                        if (read <= 0)
                                                break;
                                        out.write( buff, 0, read );
                                }
                        }
                //out.write(-1);               
                //out.write((byte)0xFF);       
                out.flush();

                //out.close();
                if ( data != null )
                        data.close();


        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                sockets.remove(socket);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions:

- Do you wait for the connection to open fully before sending from the server?
- Can you capture the stream using wireshark and see what's actually on the wire?
- In Chrome's Javascript console do you see any WebSocket related errors?
- In your onclose handler for the Javascript websocket object, can you console.log the values of code and reason from the event?

Like this:

```
ws.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("closed - code " + e.code + ", reason " + reason);
}
```

Comment: 1. yes  2. tried to write the data on a ByteArrayOutputStream and it checked out, I'll try that wireshark next 3. "Unrecognized frame opcode: 15"   4."closed - code 1006, reason "

Comment: Got it resolved. I have absolutely no idea what was wrong or what I did to solve it, but it works now. http://mlkshk.com/r/4ILY

Comment: Great. Nice image. The Chrome error indicates that somehow it received a frame where the opcode was set to 15 rather than 1. That's where wireshark would come in handy (just filter on "port 80" or whatever port you have your WebSocket server on). Also, if you found this helpful in getting to the bottom of your problem, you might consider selecting the answer so that those who search for something similar in the future will see that there might be some useful data.

Answer (score -2):

Your issue was (probably) using the old protocol.  Use the newer one...

@see

http://web-sockets.org

Has working source for a client and server (in Java).